# How to sum data from multiple rows, based on a condition in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I am trying to sum the data, based on two columns, where the values in 2 of the rows are equal. 
This is the table I have:

```
Country   | System     | Money
 AAA      | A          | 10
 AAA      | A          | 200
 AAA      | B          | 60
 BBB      | B          | 600
 BBB      | A          | 150
 BBB      | B          | 140
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
Country   | System     | Money  | SystemSum
 AAA      | A          | 10     |  210
 AAA      | A          | 200    |  210
 AAA      | B          | 60     |  60
 BBB      | B          | 600    |  740
 BBB      | A          | 150    |  150
 BBB      | B          | 140    |  740
```

This is what I have tried:

```
SUM(Money) OVER (ORDER BY Country, System ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
```

but it returns the values cumulatively. How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a window sum, but you need to remove the `rows` clause: since you specified `rows unbounded preceding`, the query only considers the preceding rows, while you want to sum over the entire partition:

```
select 
    t.*, 
    sum(money) over(partition by country, system) systemsum
from mytable as t
```

Side note: specifying `preceding` rows without an order by does not really make sense - with this syntax, you get an *undefined* set of rows being considered within the partition.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a group

```
select a.Country, a.System, a.Money, SystemSum
from tbl a inner join
(
    select Country, System,
    SUM(Money) as SystemSum
    from tbl
    group by Country, System
) b on a.Country = b.Country and a.System = b.System
```

The window function used with ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING will sum cumulatively all preceeding values of Money, hence the result you were having before

Comment: Seems like OP wants to keep the Money column.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want the sum over the combination of `Country` and `System`.  A window function is the way to go, but with `partition by` and not `order by`:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(Money) OVER (PARTITION BY Country, System)
FROM t;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, indeed the OVER(PARTITION BY ...) works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are just grouping by `(country, system)`.  Give this a try:

```sql
SELECT 
  Country, System, Money, 
  SUM(Money) OVER(PARTITION BY Country, System) AS SystemSum
FROM MyTable
```

This will give you your `SUM` based on the groups, but also return all the detailed row data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, indeed the OVER(PARTITION BY ...) works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use over partition by clause for your purposes.

```
WITH TBL(COUNTRY,SYSTEM,MONEY) AS (
 SELECT 'AAA' AS COUNTRY,'A' AS SYSTEM ,10  AS MONEY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA' AS COUNTRY,'A' AS SYSTEM ,200 AS MONEY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA' AS COUNTRY,'B' AS SYSTEM ,60  AS MONEY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BBB' AS COUNTRY,'B' AS SYSTEM ,600 AS MONEY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BBB' AS COUNTRY,'A' AS SYSTEM ,150 AS MONEY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BBB' AS COUNTRY,'B' AS SYSTEM ,140 AS MONEY FROM DUAL )
SELECT COUNTRY,SYSTEM,MONEY,SUM(MONEY)OVER(PARTITION BY COUNTRY,SYSTEM) AS SUMALL FROM TBL
```